# Indirect(), list2 name independent from list1 content?

Tags: excel, list, excel-indirect

If I understand correctly, with indirect() function the second list has to be named with an item from the first list. 
For instance, in the first column "Country" I write: USA, Canada, France, Spain... 
And then I need one column for each country with the list of their cities, and the lists have to be named according to the Country list.

I would like to create items designation on three steps: Name1, Name2 and Name3.
(With Name2 depending on Name1 and so on)

I would like list names to be independent of list conent (so each user can populate the lists according to its project).

I would like to name my lists as following:

First level list:
N

Second level lists:

N1, N2, N3, N4...

Third level lists:

N1.1, N1.2, N1.3

N2.1, N2.2

N3.1...

...

If needed to keep it acheivable, we can limit each list to maximum 10 or 15 items.

It would be great it you could help me without VBA

In advance thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the base of the following scheme:

[image]

Using These Formula:

```
F4 -> =IF(LEFT(B4;LEN($F$3))=$F$3;B4;"")
H4 -> =OR(IFERROR(FIND(".";F4;LEN($F$3)+2)>0;FALSE);F4=$F$3)
J4 -> =IF(L4="";J3;J3+1)
K4 -> =IF(M4="";"";J4)
L4 -> =IF(H4;"";F4)
M4 -> =IF(L4<>"";C4;"")
O4 -> =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(ROW(P1);$J$4:$M$17;3;);"")
P4 -> =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(ROW(P1);$K$4:$M$17;2;);"")
Q4 -> =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(ROW(P1);$K$4:$M$17;3;);"")
```

The Column J it's the Index of results not clear, than I create the column K that are clean (= without duplicated Index - but it's not necessary as shown in column O & P - same results).
The **Result - Raw** it's the searcing method without removing blanks, the **Result Rebuilt** it's the result without blanks...
The formula show only the Fields of 1° grade, not the sub-data.
You can hide the columns you don't need...
For the Results With blanks you can use only columns F / H / L / M.
*Obviously by VBA it's more simple ...*

Answer (score 0):

In the end I could do it in data validation using functions:

```
=offset()

indirect()
index()
match()
```

and lists

I think it is also possible using Vlookup() but I had problems with 3 nested vlookup.

With the 4 mentioned functions I could do 3 dropdown dynamic lists.

I am sure there is a more simple and elegent way of doing it but I got it work in the end.

I can't write all my excel sheet, but I can paste functions if it could help someone sometimes:

Nivel 1

```
=OFFSET(Topic1;0;0;COUNTA(Topic1);1)
```

Nivel 2

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(INDEX(TopicsLevel2;MATCH(C15;Topic1;0)));0;0;COUNTA(INDIRECT(INDEX(TopicsLevel2;MATCH(C15;Topic1;0))));1)
```

Nivel 3

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT($F15);0;0;COUNTA(INDIRECT($F15));1)
```

with in F15

```
=INDEX(TopicsLevel2;MATCH(C15;Topic1;0))&INDEX(Suffix;MATCH(D15;INDIRECT(INDEX(TopicsLevel2;MATCH(C15;Topic1;0)));0))
```

Name of list nivel 3 is a concatenation of names of list nivel 1 and list nivel 2.